# Print columns in reverse order from csv file

Tags: bash, csv

Input file

```
cityId;cityName;numOfBranches;numOfAtms
1;san bruno;7;11
3;milbrae;12;27
```

I want to print columns in reverse order as shown below:

```
numOfAtms;numOfBranches;cityName;cityId
11;7;san bruno;1
27;12;milbrae;3
```

Wrote python to reverse csv file, but it takes considerable time.
Any way to do it in bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {s=$NF; for (i=NF-1; i>=1; i--) s = s OFS $i; print s}' file
numOfAtms;numOfBranches;cityName;cityId
11;7;san bruno;1
27;12;milbrae;3
```

Comment: thats the exact thing I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sed

```
    while read line
    do
        echo $line | sed s/'\(.*\);\(.*\);\(.*\);\(.*\)/\4;\3;\2;\1/'
    done
```

in shell you can give command 
./reverse_pattern.sh < csv.txt, where reverse_pattern.sh is above script and csv.txt is input file

you can make it generic by using this script

```
            #!/bin/bash
            outputpat=
            inputpat=
            patternform=
            delimiter=\;

            #calulate num delimiter and form pattern
            form_pattern()
            {
                    count=$(echo "$1"|grep -o "$delimiter"| wc -w)
                    for((i=count+1;i>1;i--))
                    do
                            outputpat="$outputpat\\$i$delimiter"
                    done

                    outputpat="$outputpat\\$i"    #last word not followed by ;

                    for((i=0;i<count;i++))
                    do
                            inputpat="$inputpat\\(.*\\)$delimiter"
                    done
                    inputpat="$inputpat\\(.*\\)" #last word not followed by ;
                    patternform=yes
            }

            while read line
            do
                    if [ -z $patternform ]
                    then
                            form_pattern $line
                    fi
                    echo $line | sed s/$inputpat/$outputpat/
            done
```

Comment: Yes Varun, another trick. One problem: How can we make it generic so as to work with any number of columns in the input file ?

Comment: I have made it generic. See the above program

Answer (score 0):

With `perl` which has a built-in `reverse` function:

```sh
$ perl -F';' -lane 'print join ";", reverse @F' ip.csv
numOfAtms;numOfBranches;cityName;cityId
11;7;san bruno;1
27;12;milbrae;3
```